# Warning: Cannot find parent tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, webstorm, tsconfig

I would like to fix the warning:

> Warning: Cannot find parent tsconfig.json

in the TypeScript `Errors` tab in `IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3`. My TypeScript code lives in the `src` directory and my TypeScript output is going to `lib` as expected without the `src` folder being added to `lib`.

I consume the `lib` folder in other projects and it seems to work as expected. So this doesn't seem to be a big problem, but I occasionally have a problem with TSLint where it sometimes does not seem to pick up a `.tsx` file is JSX and lints incorrectly and seems to occasionally treat it as a normal `.ts` file. Eventually it seems to figure it out. I am wondering if that is related as my TSLint settings are configured to use `tsconfig.json`.

I have also previously had `.js` transpiled files turn up next to the `.ts` files in the `src` folder, but not since I modified my `tsconfig.json` recently.

Files as follows:

```
tsconfig.json
src/index.ts
lib/index.js
lib/index.d.ts
```

I've upgraded to TypeScript 2.1.4, but was seeing it with 2.0.10.

My `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": false,
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitUseStrict": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./lib"
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

problem is specific to TypeScript version being used (2.1.x); it is fixed in [2016.3. 2 EAP](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+EAP)

Note: this answer refers to the issue specific to IDE (WebStorm, PHPStorm, IDEA) version 2016.3: it didn't work well with TypeScript 2.1.x, showing false warnings.
If you see similar message (`Cannot find parent tsconfig.json`) in other IDE versions, it is likely a problem with your configuration: such messages are displayed if currently edited `.ts` file is not included in any `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Still there in 2016.3.3

Comment: must be a different issue. make sure that your file is included in your tsconfig.json

Comment: WebStorm 2017.1.4, still there

Comment: phpstorm 2017.2.1 still there

Comment: please see the updated answer. Your issue is clearly different, and it is likely caused by your configuration

Comment: Just got this issue after update from PhpStorm 2017.2 to 2017.3, investigating...

Comment: Upd: "Invalidating Caches / Restart" helped me.

Comment: Still there in 2017.3 - invalidate cache/restart made no difference for me.

Comment: Still there in PhpStorm 2017.3.2, using TypeScript 2.7.1.

Comment: please see my comments/answer above - your issue is different.

Comment: I see in 2018.2.5

Answer (score 22):

Try setting up `include` section in file `tsconfig.json` like in below image.
*(Note that my project's root folder is **`frontend`** and my `include` section is **`frontend/**/*`**)*.

Of course you don't need to rename your project's root folder to `frontend`.
***Only the naming should match.***

It should take effect immediately after you save the `tsconfig.json` and open a `.ts` or `.tsx` file. If it doesn't try restarting the `WebStorm/IDEA`.

*And don't forget to clear the `error` console before testing this solution. It might cache the previous messages.*

***P/S:*** I'm using `WebStorm 2016.3.1`.

[image]

---

If you were using `webpack` together with `ts-loader` the above solution would cause your builds to fail. If that was the case consider this approach instead.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how this is different to what I specified as I am using `src` in `include`

Comment: Wow, so changing the include solves it. The second part is not necessary (in 2016.3.3). Also noticed that it works if I include `src/**/*.ts` and `test/**/*.ts`. 

I suspect that at the root of this is the folder structure in the `dist` folder. If you include just `src/**/*.ts` `dist/` will contain the js output of the src folder only. However, if you include the entire project folder, `dist` will have a `src` and a `test` subfolder.

Comment: So you say that if I'm using ts-loader, I should change the WebStorm TypeScript compiler options..? For that I need to enable the WebStorm compiler, while I don't want to compile with WebStorm. I want to compile with ts-loader....

Comment: Webstorm will not compile `ts` to `js` unless you explicitly tell it to do so by pressing some buttons or right-clicking and choosing. I don't know if there is an option to automatically do the compilation on save but if you experience it you can google to turn it off. I have checked that check box and never experienced "compile on save". But to be 100% sure you should use svn, git or mercurial to back you up.

Comment: Nice to see this is still relevant in November of 21. I was worried about the age of the post. This fixed my issue as well. In the ng init process will this now be set in the tsconfig.json file?

Answer (score 4):

None of the above solutions worked for me, but I did stumble onto a tsconfig change that did. It seems the IDE is using different rules that `tsc`.

**This did NOT work**:

```
"include": ["./typings", "./src", "./test"],
```

**This did work**:

```
"include": ["./typings/**/*", "./src/**/*", "./test/**/*"],
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the "version number" to your tsconfig.json file.

```
{
    "version": "2.1.4",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "jsx": "react",
        "allowJs": false,
        "isolatedModules": false,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noImplicitUseStrict": true,
        "noEmitHelpers": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noLib": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "inlineSources": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "outDir": "./lib"
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ],
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "atom": {
        "rewriteTsconfig": false
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that just now, but unfortunately it does not seem to work.

Comment: I got an Angular2 project with the same problem today, after the upgrade to TypeScript 2.1.4 i deleted all folders and files that was generated during the project installation/setup.. then i installed it again, my setup installs folders like: typings, node_modules, ce_sources and tmp, for me. Maybe you need to delete all the generated folders and files from your setup, cause some old or wrong file stills there. Hope that helps you