# Warning: Cannot find parent tsconfig.json (WebStorm 2016.3.2)

Tags: typescript, webstorm

Using TypeScript 2.1.4 and WebStorm 2016.3.2, I'm getting this error:
`Warning: Cannot find parent tsconfig.json` in certain files.

It compiles fine without this issue if I call `tsc` manually, but it in the IDE it causes some ES6 features to go unrecognized (Promise, Map, etc.).

Here's the tsconfig:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "files": [
    "app/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

I know this has been mentioned previously: [Warning: Cannot find parent tsconfig.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41072254/warning-cannot-find-parent-tsconfig-json) but the accepted solution there is to use WebStorm 2016.3.2 (the version I am using).

Comment: Just in case: please try `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE (in case if you have not tried it yet).

Comment: option "files" doesn't allow wildcards. Use option "include" instead. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/40729219/1057218

Comment: I cant try this out till I'm back home in January, but thanks for the suggestions, I'll get back to you on the success of it.

Comment: @Tiedye did you manage to fix this?

Comment: It just kinda went away... I created a new project, updated typescript, and the problem vanished

Comment: I have this issue, I try @LazyOne, not working. I update my `webstorm` to `2017.1.4` version, not working. I rename my project name, not working.

Comment: @novaline Same for me. Looks like its a typescript issue